# Does WP8 DeviceStatus.ApplicationCurrentMemoryUsage Property take into acount native allocations?

Tags: c#, memory-management, windows-phone-8, native-code

I can't find this specified in the documentation, so I'm wondering if anyone has any experience regarding this?

I need to know about all the memory the application is consuming, therefor a sum of what was allocated in the native project I'm referencing and what is managed in the managed application.

The documentation I'm looking at can be found at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.info.devicestatus(v=vs.105).aspx

Bonus: While we are at it, can I find out how much memory is allocated to each part of the application (native vs managed)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `DeviceStatus.ApplicationCurrentMemoryUsage` does include the total memory the application is using: both Native and Managed.

You can ask [GC.GetTotalMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.gettotalmemory.aspx) how much managed memory it *thinks* is used, but I've found that this isn't reliable.

As per MSDN:

> Retrieves the number of bytes currently thought to be allocated.

**Update:**

There is a brief example of how to determine how close you are to your memory limits at [DeviceStatus.ApplicationMemoryUsageLimit Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.info.devicestatus.applicationmemoryusagelimit%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), but it doesn't explicitly call out different types of memory. I suspect that is as close as you are going to get to a reference at MSDN for now.

Comment: Is this from personal experience or can you provide an reference?

Comment: This is from personal experience of writing and debugging a C++/C# hybrid app. For WP8 if you hit the app memory limits, the OS will kill your process immediately - `ApplicationCurrentMemoryUsage` is the property you need to watch for that.

Comment: I see. Well it is what I expect it to do, I'm just hoping someone will provide a reference...

Comment: ApplicationMemoryUsageLimit page gives a bigger hint that this is the correct API to use, but it isn't particularly explicit.